# Check out the return value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'll check the value returned by the function if it was one thing and do another task, but it does not work otherwise?

```
$.post('ajaxs.php', {
      name: name_,
      mail: mail_,
      matn: matn_,
      url: url_,
      id: id_
  },function (data) {
      $('#readmore').html(data);

      if (data == 1) {
          $('#readmore').css({
              "border-color": "#00CC00",
              "border-width": "1px",
              "border-style": "solid"
          });
      } else {
          $('#readmore').css({
              "border-color": "#ff0000",
              "border-width": "1px",
              "border-style": "solid"
          });
      }
});
```

Comment: This code you've posted is bad , you have an extra closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$.post('ajaxs.php', {
    name: name_,
    mail: mail_,
    matn: matn_,
    url: url_,
    id: id_
}, function (data) {
    $('#readmore').html(data)
               .css('border', '1px solid ' + $.trim(data) == "1" ?  '#00CC00' : '#ff0000');
});
```

Comment: @user1753323 - Did you add jQuery, use a document ready function, get the ID right, and does the server return the proper data. What error messages are you getting in the console etc ?

Comment: Yes, I've added the jQuery document
And the code that you have not taken any action

Comment: try adding a `console.log(data)` in the success function, and open the console (F12) and check for errors and see if the data is logged.

Comment: Dear friend:
Data variable returns the number 1, but do not compare.
What is wrong with my code please?

Comment: If it's a string, you should check for a string, see my updated answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately else runs.
The one is back!
Please if you are troubleshooting an error on my code